# UID of first RFID Scanned display on textfiled (jSSC Arduino and java(Netbeans JFrame))

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, arduino

I have a Netbeans proj. that when the button is pressed it will perform this:

```
if(!jTextField1.getText().isEmpty()){
       if(serialPort != null){
            try {
                serialPort.removeEventListener();

                if(serialPort.isOpened()){
                    serialPort.closePort();
                }

            } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName())
                        .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
jTextField1.setText(null); 
portInitialize(serialPort);
PortSerialReader(serialPort);
jButton1.setEnabled(false);
```

when the button is pressed, the user can now scan the RFID, the problem is when the user scan it multiple times, all the UIDs will also be displayed in the textfield.
For example, the user scanned: ***F9D6A12A***, it will be displayed, but when the user scanned another RFID, the display on the textfield will looked like this: ***F9D6A12A F9D6A12A***. I only want to display the UID of the first RFID scanned. what do i need to change in the code?

```
public void PortSerialReader(SerialPort sPort){
    try{
        sPort.setEventsMask(MASK_RXCHAR);
        sPort.addEventListener((SerialPortEvent serialPortEvent) -> {
            if(serialPortEvent.isRXCHAR()){
                try{
                    String st =  sPort.readString(serialPortEvent.getEventValue());
                    System.out.println(st); 
                    jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText() + st);
                    jButton1.setEnabled(true);
                }catch(SerialPortException e){
                    Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName())
                          .log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
                } 
            }
        });  
    }catch(SerialPortException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName())
              .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
}
```

Here is the Arduino Code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define SS_PIN 10
#define RST_PIN 9
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance.

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600); // Initialize serial communications with the PC
    SPI.begin();            // Init SPI bus
    mfrc522.PCD_Init(); // Init MFRC522 card    
}

void loop() {
    String code = "";
    // Look for new cards
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
        return;
    }

    // Select one of the cards
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
        return;
    }

    for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) {
      code += String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? "0" :"");
      code += String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
    }
    Serial.println(code);
    mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();
}
```

Comment: Inside you event listener, trying adding `sPort.removeEventListener(this)`...

Comment: i already tried it,yes it displayed only the first RFID scanned but incomplete and the characters not displayed was instead displayed on the next available scan.

Comment: How do you know when the rfid is finished been read?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Is there a terminating character? Is there a delay? I'm assuming that the length is probably fixed. If you know when the rfid has finished been read, you know when you can stop reading or caring about new input

Comment: i don't have anything like that, how do i create one?

Comment: Well, if can't guarantee  the length, then maybe before mfrc522.PICC_HaltA(), you need to write a terminating character you can detect at the other end

Comment: i think the length of each UID is the the same but what do you mean by terminating character and how to create one?

Comment: A terminating character is a character (may be `null` or `/0`) you add to the byte stream to tell whoever is reading it that they've reached the end of the transmission, but without having to close the stream in the process, you see it a lot in Socket based programming.  The terminator can be anything you want, but typically is some kind of control/non-printing character.

Comment: Not been familiar with Arduino, I can say how it should be done, other than the fact you want to write it to the serial port after you've written the RFID, when you read the text from the port, you want inspect it to see if it contains the terminator at some point

Answer (score 0):

finally found the mistakes.

at your arduino

change `Serial.println(code);` to `Serial.print(code);`

then, at java source you should set the byte count by changing

`String st =  sPort.readString(serialPortEvent.getEventValue());`

to `String st =  sPort.readString(8)` (or total number of strings code from arduino)

and the last, change `jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText() + st);`

to `jTextField1.setText(st);`

hope this will help you out